# Identifying whether or not all character strings in a vector are identical

Tags: r

I am trying to check if strings in a rolling window are all identical to each other, and if they are, report the identical value in a new column, and if not, report an NA. My data looks sorta like this:

```
Sample_ID   distance    Sr87Sr86    LAME
2014_0385   669          0.70868    SAL
2003_0141   702          0.7079     SAL
2008_0089   644          0.70818    SAL
2013_6380   452          0.70813    SAL
2006_0328   1226         0.70838    FW
2014_0106   784          0.7086     SAL
2006_0028   1750         0.70853    SAL
2007_0241   462          0.70621    SAL
2011_0313   393          0.70645    SAL
2010_0233   880          0.70688    SAL
```

where the LAME column is what I want to check if they match.

What I want it to look like is something like the following:

```
Sample_ID   distance    Sr87Sr86    LAME    LAME_roll
2014_0385   669          0.70868    SAL     SAL
2003_0141   702          0.7079     SAL     SAL
2008_0089   644          0.70818    SAL     NA
2013_6380   452          0.70813    SAL     NA
2006_0328   1226         0.70838    FW      NA
2014_0106   784          0.7086     SAL     SAL
2006_0028   1750         0.70853    SAL     SAL
2007_0241   462          0.70621    SAL     SAL
2011_0313   393          0.70645    SAL     SAL
2010_0233   880          0.70688    SAL     SAL
```

In which I used a left-aligned 3 row rolling window. The specific window size or being left aligned isn't that important, the point would be that as it rolls along, it checks that all values in the window are the same.

What I have currently attempted is the following:

```
data$LAME_roll = rollapply(data$LAME, width = 3, align = "left", FUN = all.identical, partial = TRUE, fill = NA)
```

where all.identical is a custom function doing the following:

```
all.identical = function(x) {
  if(length(unique(x)) > 1) {
    NA
  } else {
    unique(x)
  }
}
```

This seems to work but if you ask to view the rows where the LAME_roll is "NA" with `View(data[data$LAME_roll == "NA",]`, it returns rows where all values are NA, including the row names. What's going on? Is there a better way to accomplish this goal? Or is there a way to get rid of those NA rows? When viewing the data frame they don't appear, only when trying to view the subset of data.

Comment: To address one of your questions, `==` behaves strangely with `NA` in R. Try using the builtin `is.na()` instead, i.e. `View(data[is.na(data$LAME_roll), ])`

Comment: @klumbard THANK YOU! That insight, applied to a couple other places in my code, fixed the issues I was having. I had no idea that '==' operator didn't place nice with "NA". I am pretty sure the custom function I wrote is a slow, less than ideal way of doing it, but it works, thanks.